# Use string as vairable in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I have variables `$person-color` and `$animal-color` in a separate `variables.scss` file which I want to use in my `main.scss` file.

What I want to achieve is the following CSS:

```
.person-container {
    background: blue;
}

.animal-container {
    background: red;
}
```

My SCSS looks like below:

```
$items: person animal;

@each $item in $items {
  .$item-container {
      background: #{$item}-color;
  }
}
```

This won't work. But I want to expand the value of the variable in the string `#{$item}-color`. Is there a way to get the output above without using a map?

Comment: I prefer you to test on http://www.sassmeister.com/

Comment: I can't change those variable names :(

Comment: Just for clarification, you're talking about variable variables right? As in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Note: Sass does not support dynamic declaration of variables. I.e., this will not work: `$#{$some_variable_holding_a_variable_name}: #000`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partials need to start with an underscore ex. `_variables.scss` or else it will compile into a `.css`

**_variables.scss**

```
$person: red;
$animal: blue;
```

**main.scss**

```
@import 'variables';

$items: person $person, animal $animal;

@each $item in $items {
  $key: nth($item, 1);
  $value: nth($item, 2);

  .#{$key}-container {
      background: $value;
  }
}
```

Edit: Now should give you the right results!